# How do I fix the line formatting for my nav Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, I have this responsive nav in Bootstrap. When you minimize the window, the nav transforms and allows you to expand the content. But when you expand the content, the lines, background color and logo seem to look unprofessional? How do I fix? It doesn't look right....

```css
.navbar {
  background: #007BC4 !important;
  padding: 10px !important;
}

.nav a {
  color: white !important;
}

#sign_up {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}

#email_form, #password_form {
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #007BC4;
}

#login_button {
  background: #0092ea !important;
  border: 1px solid #005c93;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px !important;
}

#login_button:hover {
  background: #007BC4 !important;
}

#remember_label {
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#forgot_password {
  color: white !important;
  position: relative;
  left: 65px;
  font-size: 13px !important;
}

#remember {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}

.navbar-brand{
 height:auto;
 padding: 0px 15px;
}
.navbar-brand img{ max-width:250px;width:100%;}
.navbar-nav > li > a{padding-top: 0;}
@media (max-width:1000px) {
 .navbar-header {
     float: left;
  width:25%;
 }
 .navbar-brand{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 12px; 
  padding:0;
 }
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
 .navbar-header {
     float: left;
  width:100%;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
 }
 .navbar-brand{
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
 }
 .navbar-brand img {
     max-width: 200px;
 }
 .navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 7.5px 0;
 }
 .navbar-nav > li > a{
  padding: 10px 0;
 }
 .navbar-form{
  float: left;
 }
 #sign_up {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0px;
 }
 #email_form, #password_form{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
 }
 #login_button{
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS Files -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="Buy Sell Rent Everyting">
                <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a">
            </a>
            
        </div>
        
        
        <!-- Sign Up -->
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
            
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li> <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id='sign_up'> Sign Up </button></a> </li>
            </ul>
   <!-- Login -->
   <div class='navbar-form navbar-right'>
     <form action='#' method='post'>
       <input type='text' placeholder='Email' id='email_form'>
       <input type='text' placeholder='Password' type='password' id='password_form'>
       <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id='login_button'>Login</button>
     </form>
     
     <input type='checkbox' name='remember' id='remember'> <label for='remember' id='remember_label'> Remember me </label>
     
     <a href='#' id='forgot_password'> Forgot Password? </a>
     
   </div>
   
  </div>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- JS Files -->
  <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: You actually need to learn basic Design & implementing them in CSS. Please do not ask question like how do I make look this better.

Comment: What looks professional is subjective, if you are looking for design help try http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @sandip_rb Ok, but how do I fix the lines of the expanding section? I'm not asking for professionals design, but coding assistance.

Comment: Update/edit the question to say that. Right now the title says "How can I my nav look more professional.." which would make people think that's what you're asking.

Comment: @ZimSystem I changed it. Can you help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `navbar-form` class, and then a few small tweaks to make the top border transparent:

http://www.codeply.com/go/MVehZfspvB

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button button="" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="Buy Sell Rent Everyting">
                <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Sign Up -->
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="sign_up"> Sign Up </button>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Login -->
            <div class="navbar-right">
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email_form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" id="password_form">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="login_button">Login</button>
                </form>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">
                <label for="remember" id="remember_label"> Remember me </label>
                <a href="#" id="forgot_password"> Forgot Password? </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Link works fine, and regardless of the link, the code is in the question. Have you tried it?